# MIPS disassembling: lui followed by lbu

Tags: mips, disassembly, ida

I'm disassembling a firmware using IDA  (mipsb processor)

I'm seeing this a lot in this IDA dissasm.

```
lui       $t9 , 0x802f
```

...does nothing with `$t9` ...and doesn't jump..

```
lbu      $t9, 0x200+var_24($sp)
```

And it makes no sense to me.
in first line:  `$t9` becomes 0x802F0000
in 2nd line: `$t9` becomes whatever byte is store at that location on the stack.

If i'm right, then what's the point?  Is this a mishap of the compiler used, or  maybe a programmer's mishap, or am i missing something ?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me either. Maybe a old broken compiler or some arcane way of doing a NOP...

Comment: The code might have been compiled with `-O0`.  Optimization would usually remove nonsense like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shall remain a mystery how it got here, but obviously the `lui $t9 , 0x802F` has absolutely no purpose in this code (and other parts of the firmware i'm looking at, i see same thing.. same nonsense...with same values `lui $t9, 0x802f`)

hsikcah's answer is definitely wrong. (`lbu` loads a single byte, but it zero'es out the first 3 bytes of the register)..

The answer seems to be my original guess. It's either a compiler's artifact or a coder's nonsense that wasn't removed by the compiler (also suggested by **m0skit0**'s and **markgz**'s comments)

Answer (score 3):

You didn't show what happens before this. If there's a branch just before the lui, the code at the destination of the branch could be using the loaded t9 value.

Additionally, disable simplification of instructions in the processor-specific options. I suspect that the store at 800D8328 is using the t9 value for the part of the address, and IDA simplified it by substituting the complete value.

Answer (score 0):

The lbu instruction is not sign extended. As a result suppose 0x200+var_24($sp) contains 0x12 after these 2 instructions the value of $t9 will become ox80200012. These pairings of instructions are common for loading a 32 bit memory address. As a common example would be iterating through a data structure on the heap.

Comment: hmmm...  so you're saying  whatever is already there, in the first 3 bytes of $t9, will still be there after a lbu $t9 ... basically acting like an ADD instruction.. to add an offset to  a base

Comment: i added a picture.  Note `$t6 = 0x000000EE`  and the `bne` below it comparing `$t9` and `$t6` ....  that `bne` would be useless if what you're saying is true, right ?

Comment: i mean the comparison in the bne.. would always be false if you're right ... but i think you're wrong

Comment: Sorry, your picture does not match your question. In that screencap the lbu is going into T8, not T9. My answer still stands as you can read the mips instruction set and see that lbu does not sign extend.

Comment: ??? i highlighted $t9 for you   look on first line, see yellow... follow yellow.  Sure `lbu` is `load byte unsigned`. But a byte is a byte, and `$t9` holds 4 bytes. You're saying the other 3 bytes in `$t9` remain unchanged, but code shows otherwise...as i know for a fact that `bne` will sometimes jump and sometimes not jump..just based on what byte is compared to 0xEE

Comment: The first instruction loads 0x802f into the high word of $t9. The second loads only the byte from the stack into _$t8_, not $t9. The MIPS docs say: The immediate value is shifted left 16 bits and stored in the register. The lower 16 bits are zeroes.. This means $t9 becomes 0x802f0000. The second instruction is $t8. lbu is not sign extended which means that only the 8 bits are changed. In your case you have to go higher in the assembly to find the initial value of $t8.

Comment: lol .. now i think you're pretending to not see. FOLLOW THE YELLOW !

Comment: anyways, all LOAD instructions modify the whole register, not just a part of it. As in, if you load byte unsigned (LBU), the other 3 bytes are zero'ed out. If you load byte (LB) the other 3 bytes depend on the sign: zero'ed out if positive, or FF'ed if negative. This is what you don't understand.